# How to update dataframe from column list values to another column values based on list values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new in python, I am fetching data as JSON and I transferred into dataframes. I want to update disks column value with another dataframe column value based on volume_id actually it is kind of replace value. Data' are examples not exact.

df1

```
            instance_id                           disks
0   i-0c314bb8d450cvv95     [vol-08662a47184e0b3b3, vol-07a18ce1652ff88f3,...
1   i-064e75dvdb8fb8d75     [vol-0f2911a1d0b9a521e, vol-0c28d13ada32564da]
2   i-04a85cb1dccvd895b     [vol-069bf62bf82f32402, vol-0424a5deb55024a47]
3   i-0572cvvdf430d7475     [vol-0e3b471dcbf0fbd47, vol-003d7443d8696a691]
4   i-0fe4cbbfsfgb51c14     [vol-0bcf2aa4f873cc296, vol-03d2a0f318973aaec]
```

df2

```
                  VolumeID          instance_id  size type
0    vol-02d8942df26543361  i-0533ae59fgt06cb7a    37  gp3
1    vol-0bcf2aa4f8754c296  i-0fe4cbb54df151c14   450  st1
2    vol-069bf84bf82f32402  i-04a85cfgd489d895b    50  gp3
3    vol-0424a5deb54524a47  i-04a85cb1fdg45895b   150  st1
4    vol-0871a4e6f387db693  i-0f2ae964gfdgf3caa    50  gp3
```

desired df

```
            instance_id       disks
0   i-0c314bb8d450cvv95     50 100 200
1   i-064e75dvdb8fb8d75     65 150
2   i-04a85cb1dccvd895b     50 150
3   i-0572cvvdf430d7475     100 150
4   i-0fe4cbbfsfgb51c14     80 150
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are the root and data variables in the disks column of your desired data frame?

Comment: I think you want df.merge() but question is unclear

Comment: Actually it was just label for df2 size column values

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 mapping_dict=dict(zip(df2["VolumeID"],df2["size"]))
 df1["disks"]=df1["disks"].apply(lambda x:list(map(lambda value:mapping_dict[value],x)))
```

Btw, I don't think it's the best answer but it should work

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
res = ( df1
    .set_index('instance_id')
    .explode('disks')
    .join(df2.set_index('VolumeID'), on='disks')['size']
    .groupby('instance_id')
    .agg(disks=list)
    .reset_index() )
```

Explanation:

- use `join()` to map each `VolumeID` to the volumes in the exploded `disks` column to a row in `df2`, then turn the resulting `size` values into a list for each group using `groupby()` on `instance_id`.
- Note: This assumes `VolumeID` is a unique key. If instead the unique key were the composite `instance_id, VolumeID`, a different approach would be required.

Sample input:

```
df1:

  instance_id                        disks
0        i_00  [vol-000, vol-001, vol-002]
1        i_01  [vol-010, vol-011, vol-012]
2        i_02  [vol-020, vol-021, vol-022]
3        i_03  [vol-030, vol-031, vol-032]
4        i_04  [vol-040, vol-041, vol-042]
5        i_05  [vol-050, vol-051, vol-052]
6        i_06  [vol-060, vol-061, vol-062]
7        i_07  [vol-070, vol-071, vol-072]
8        i_08  [vol-080, vol-081, vol-082]
9        i_09  [vol-090, vol-091, vol-092]

df2:

   VolumeID instance_id  size type
0   vol-000          na     0   na
1   vol-001          na     5   na
2   vol-002          na    10   na
3   vol-010          na    15   na
4   vol-011          na    20   na
5   vol-012          na    25   na
6   vol-020          na    30   na
7   vol-021          na    35   na
8   vol-022          na    40   na
9   vol-030          na    45   na
10  vol-031          na    50   na
11  vol-032          na    55   na
12  vol-040          na    60   na
13  vol-041          na    65   na
14  vol-042          na    70   na
15  vol-050          na    75   na
16  vol-051          na    80   na
17  vol-052          na    85   na
18  vol-060          na    90   na
19  vol-061          na    95   na
20  vol-062          na   100   na
21  vol-070          na   105   na
22  vol-071          na   110   na
23  vol-072          na   115   na
24  vol-080          na   120   na
25  vol-081          na   125   na
26  vol-082          na   130   na
27  vol-090          na   135   na
28  vol-091          na   140   na
29  vol-092          na   145   na
```

Output:

```
  instance_id            disks
0        i_00       [0, 5, 10]
1        i_01     [15, 20, 25]
2        i_02     [30, 35, 40]
3        i_03     [45, 50, 55]
4        i_04     [60, 65, 70]
5        i_05     [75, 80, 85]
6        i_06    [90, 95, 100]
7        i_07  [105, 110, 115]
8        i_08  [120, 125, 130]
9        i_09  [135, 140, 145]
```